# Using NSArrayController to bind model objects to an inspector view, how to catch special cases like empty and multiple selections?

Tags: macos, cocoa, cocoa-bindings

I have inspector view and because it contains a lot of UI I want to explore cocoa bindings to connect it to the model. The inspector view will update depending on the currently selected object in an outline view and the inspector view displays controls to alter properties (like colour, name, shape etc.) that can be changed.

This works well **when only one row in the outline view is selected** because the view has a one-to-one relationship with the model object. However, there are two special cases that I want to be able to catch:

1. Empty selection

   If no items in the outline view are selected I want to display a special "No items selected view" placeholder view.
2. Multiple selection

   If multiple items are selected I can either display a "Multiple items selected view" placeholder view or I can decide to let the changes apply globally to all selected model objects.

My question is how can these special cases be caught when using bindings? Moreover, how can I do behaviour "A" when there is an empty selection and behaviour "B" when there is a multiple section. This sort of thing is trivial when using target/action because you can just code the logic into the action method.

Bindings seem great when propagating changes to values but I'm unsure how to go about implementing bindings that require different decisions based on current selection state.